# Finding out which of a number of mutually exclusive, potentially non-terminating Bools is True

Tags: haskell, concurrency

(Longish question, the concrete questions are at the bottom)

I'm working on a hobby project dealing with subsets of countable types, and I want to find out which (possibly infinite) 'set' a particular value belongs to.

So, I've got a number of mutually exclusive, potentially non-terminating, `Bool` values (in my case, the characteristic values of the sets for a given value) such that:

- **Exactly** one of them will evaluate to `True` in finite time.
- The rest will either evaluate to `False` in finite time, or their computation won't terminate.

and my goal is to find out which one of them returns `True`.

The type signature would best fit my needs is (I think!)

```
decide :: [(Bool, b)] -> b
```

(but I'm open to suggestions here; I can do the `b` lookup at a later stage, say, if `Int` work better).

Morally `decide` should be equivalent to `snd . (\[x] -> x) . filter fst`, if all the computations terminate (if `\[x] -> x` explodes that's a programmer error I'd rather see early).

Here's an example of the desired behaviour (I'm deliberately not using `even` and `odd` in the example, because the indicator functions of the sets I'm working with might not ever return `False`!):

```
type Natural = Integer
isNatural :: Integer -> Bool
isNatural = (>= 0)

evenOnNatural :: Natural -> Maybe Boolean
evenOnNatural x = decide [( x `elem` [0,2..],     Just True),
                          ( x `elem` [1,3..],     Just False),
                          ( not . isNatural $ x , Nothing)]

-- evenOnNatural 2 should be Just True
-- evenOnNatural 3 should be Just False
-- evenOnNatural (-1) should be Nothing (as it is outside the 'domain')
```

---

I've cobbled together the following code, which does what I want for this example (and can serve as a reference implementation):

```
import Control.Monad(when)
import Control.Concurrent(forkIO,killThread)
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import System.IO.Unsafe(unsafePerformIO) -- Oh dear!

decide :: [(Bool, a)] -> a
decide xs = unsafePerformIO $ do
    mv <- newEmptyMVar
    let actions = map (\(b,val) -> when b (putMVar mv val)) xs 
    threadIds <- mapM forkIO actions
    result <- takeMVar mv
    mapM_ killThread threadIds -- probably wrong, doesn't kill subthreads
    return result
```

I'm thinking about using [Data.Unamb](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unamb-0.2.5/docs/Data-Unamb.html)'s `unambs` and `assuming` combinators in the following way:

```
decide' :: [(Bool, a)] -> a
decide' = unambs . map (uncurry assuming)
```

which certainly *looks* a lot better! And I'm sure [Conal Elliott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127335/conal) is a better programmer than me :-)

But before I do this, I would like answers to the following questions:

- Is `decide` already available in, or implementable with, the Haskell Platform?
- Does the solution with `unambs` have the behaviour I want with respect to mutual exclusiveness?
- Are there any other important issues I should be aware of?

[ I realise this question in a less specific form might be better off at Programmers SE or at Code Review SE; I've tried to formulate it in such a way that it's unambiguously (ha!) answerable. ]

Comment: Yes, you are using `unambs` correctly, I think this implements your problem. `decide` might be more reliable since we've observed problems  with `unamb` killing its children in deeply nested trees (such as what `unambs` creates), unfortunately, but *in theory* `decide'` is the way to go.  I suggest you try it and see.

Comment: @luqui: I just got around to doing just that, but I think I need to start compiling, play with RTS options, and/or fire up my Linux VM, since `let n = 10^12 :: Integer in unamb n (last [1..n])` doesn't seem to want to return today (Haskell Platform 2014.2 on Win 7, ghci without RTS options, unamb-0.2.5). I'll go investigate a bit more, as it looks like I'm doing something wrong :-)

Comment: oh yeah, that's expected. `unamb` can't handle process trees that big -- it's essentially doing what `decide` is doing, so you can imagine...

Comment: In the example in my comment, I see two values being raced - `n` and `last [1..n]`, so the process tree is rather small... I would expect the quicker computation to kill off the slower, but maybe I'm misunderstanding something about what `unamb` does?

Comment: oh, right, braino.   Thread contexts switch on allocations, so for some particularly simple computations they will never switch, but anything nontrivial will.  But I'm not surprised, we have these kinds of problems with `unamb` -- threads weren't made for this...

Comment: One option for your case is to scrap all of this and instead think about a list of functions `[a -> Either (Bool, b) a]` representing steps in individual loops. To recurse, `zipWith (fmap . ($)) fns states`. Then you've got a breadth-first search with no direct threading necessary.

Comment: @ChrisDrost, great idea.  `[forall a. a -> Either (Bool, b) a]` (modulo newtype wrapping to counter the impredicative types) is more accurate and expressive, albeit trickier to recurse with.

Comment: @ChrisDrost: that definitely sounds doable! Especially since I'm going to be running down an enumeration of the elements *anyway*. It's a slightly leaky abstraction but that can be papered over with  enough combinators. I'll give it a whirl and see how far I get.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe corresponds, I think , to the `Searchable` class here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/countable

The trick, which is cool, is described here: http://math.andrej.com/2007/09/28/seemingly-impossible-functional-programs/

There are some slides on further research here among elsewhere: http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mhe/.talks/popl2012/escardo-popl2012.pdf